# How many elements in a tuple?

Tags: tuples, computer-science

How many elements can a tuple hold?

For example, a pair can hold 2 elements. So similarly, how many numbers can a tuple hold? I tried 3 elements and it worked.  I was just wondering.

Comment: As many elements as you like.  Or at least as many as can be stored in or addressed by the host system.  Why assume there's a limit?

Comment: You mentioned `I tried 3 elements`. Where did you try that? Post your code or name/tag the programming language.

Comment: It was for bellman ford algorithm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tuple is nothing more than a finite ordered list. The number of elements it can hold can be any non-negative integer.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics and computer science (relational algebra) a **[tuple](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)** is the term for a data-structure. As this a tuple is defined as *finite ordered list*, containing 0 or more elements.

You also name tuples by their number of elements (n) as **n-tuple**. So your mentioned `pair` would be colloquial for a *2-tuple*, whereas 3 elements are forming a *3-tuple*, and so on.

This data-structure can be implemented differently by various programming language. For example in Python a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) is [not just a list](http://jtauber.com/blog/2006/04/15/python_tuples_are_not_just_constant_lists/).